# enabling pg_connect in PHP when running as Apache module

Tags: php, apache, postgresql

I have an embedded device which has Apache running and PHP as an Apache module. A PostgreSQL database is also running on this device. The device is running some flavor of Linux on PowerPC.

I want to use a webservice written in PHP to connect to this PostgreSQL database.

The problem is that PHP/Apache does not have pgsql (`php.pgsql.so` module) support and I don't see a `php.ini` anywhere on this device.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try 
find / | grep php.ini to locate the file?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to install the PostgreSQL extension for PHP, it doesn't have anything to do with Apache. Here's some more info, if you're compiling PHP from source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pgsql.installation.php

Comment: That is what I mentioned I can install php extention with somethig like apt-get install php5-pgsql'. I need to do it manually. And how to do is what I am asking.

Comment: If you can install it via apt-get, why do you need to do it manually? If you meant that you can't and don't know how to do it manually - how did you compile PHP in the first place?